# Removing 'Search the Store' from Windows 'Open with' context menu

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu, windows-store

I've been tweaking Windows 10 to better suit my aesthetic, successfully removing a lot of things I don't like. There's on thing I'm stuck at now, though - the 'Search the Store' link in the 'Open with' context menu. Despite going through the registry, I've not been able to find a way to hide that item.

Has anyone ever managed to remove it? I'm willing to use ResHacker or similar software if needed.

[image]

Comment: in regedit go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer 
create a new a 32-bit DWORD value named NoUseStoreOpenWith and set it to 1, restart windows

Comment: @arana No explorer folder under Windows in Regedit.

Comment: you have to create it then, if you are not comfortable with it, you can downloadd an utility that does this for you http://winaero.com/download.php?view.1796 under the BEHAVIOUR settings
http://i.imgur.com/XXvUcvW.png

Comment: Seems hardcoded in system files ([How Remove “Search the Store” from Open With context menu?](https://forums.mydigitallife.net/threads/how-remove-%E2%80%9Csearch-the-store%E2%80%9D-from-open-with-context-menu.70941/)), so little hope.

Answer (score 1):

The entry is created by `shell32.dll`, which is registered as a context menu handler in the following registry key: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Open With`. The default value is `{09799AFB-AD67-11d1-ABCD-00C04FC30936}`. If you go to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{09799AFB-AD67-11d1-ABCD-00C04FC30936}\InProcServer32` you will find a default value of `%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll`.

Without a registry key to turn this setting on or off, the file needs to be edited to remove the entry.

Answer (score 1):

This can be disable using the following Group Policy setting:

```
Administrative Templates > System > Internet Communication Management > Internet Communication settings > Turn off access to the Store
```

Set to "Enabled" to disable "Search the Store".

Alternatively, it may be configured with the following registry value:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explo‌​rer
    NoUseStoreOpenWith (DWORD)
```

Set to `0x00000001` to disable "Search the Store".

Comment: It seems like that group policy setting can be done both in system configuration and user configuration.

Comment: Tried on 1709, context menu item doesn't go away after enabling this policy, even after a restart if you were wondering.

Answer (score -1):

I am also removing "not required stuff" from Windows 10. As per Forest original post, I cannot remove "Search the store" (or "Search the Microsoft Store") from Explorer "Open With" context menu; as per the picture at the top of this post.

Knowing that:
HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\NoUseStoreOpenWith =1
and
HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\NoUseStoreOpenWith =1
only disable the Prompt to "look for an app in the store" when opening files with unknown extention.

And knowing that enabling the group policy:
Administrative Templates > System > Internet Communication Management > _
Internet Communication settings > Turn off access to the Store
does the same as the regkey above.

Did anyone find an answer to this question? How do we remove "Search the Microsoft Store" from Explorer "Open With" context menu?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1112975)